# unpackagedMetadata setting in sfdx-project.json not being respected

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, sfdx-error

I am using :

[image]

My sfdx-project.json:

```
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "source",
      "default": true,
      "package": "complaints",
      "versionName": "ver 0.1",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "unpackagedMetadata": {
        "path": "testmetadata"
    },
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "package": "base@0.1.0-32"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "testmetadata",
      "default": false
    }
  ],
```

My project organization:

[image]

Running:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create --package complaints --installationkeybypass --wait 2000 --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json
```

Or

```
sfdx package:version:create --package complaints --installation-key-bypass --wait 2000 --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json --code-coverage
```

I keep getting this in my test class:

```
 Some_Test: Field does not exist: Branch__c on User
along with other missing metadata in classes folder.
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Does your test class have a "hard" (i.e. resolved at compile-time) reference to `Branch__c`? That is, do you have something like `new User(Branch__c = 'value');`, `if(myUser.Branch__c == 'value')`, or `List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Branch__c FROM User];`? If so, then that's a problem. Unpackaged metadata only helps with "soft" (i.e. resolved at run-time) references like `user.put('Branch__c', 'value');` and `List<User> users = (List<User>)Database.query('SELECT Id, Branch__c FROM User');`